# .html как часть slug

Tags: symfony, route, slug

роут

> p:
>    url: /:cat_slug/:slug
>    param: { module: p, action: index }
>     requirements:
>       slug:  \w+

пример

```
сайт.домен/категория/товар
```

могу ли я задать правило для роута где slug может быть как `/категория/новый-слаг` так и `/категория/старый-слаг.html`
то есть **.html** чтоб воспринималось как параметр, не обрезая расширение?

в итоге `slug = старый-слаг.html`

Answer (score 1):

создал два правила в роутах.
так как у меня старые ссылки оканчиваются на **.html**
в случае если присуствует .html вызываю новый экшин, который делает редирект на товар