# Русскоязычный вариант для термина slug

Tags: терминология, faq

Как корректно на русский переводится термин 'slug'?

Контекст употребления можно найти в этих вопросах:

- [Создание ЧПУ для категорий сайта с помощью PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/715044/213987)
- [.html как часть slug](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/489076/213987)
- [Обновление slug в django](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/493611/213987)
- [Как передать slug в urls.py](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/590407/213987)

Судя по всему это что-то имеющее отношение к ЧПУ (человекопонятный url), но что именно?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как перевести slug в Wordpress с русского на английский?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619567/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-slug-%d0%b2-wordpress-%d1%81-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Технически *обычно* это **уникальный человекочитаемый ключ для поиска**, который может не только идентифицировать единственную запись, но и быть осмысленным для пользователей при прямом прочтении. В конкретных случаях бывают и другие требования, вроде безопасности для вставки в URL (не всякие символы разрешены), определённой максимальной длины или чувствительности к регистру.

Почему именно так? Потому что термин в основном употребяется в отношении замены "непонятного `id`" на "понятный `slug`" в соответствующих технических статьях, руководствах и документации к связанным библиотекам (например: [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id), [`eloquent-sluggable`](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable#background-what-is-a-slug)). Потому что при генерации этих slug'ов возникает несколько стандартных задач:

- спасти читаемость при фильтрации символов (например, что делать с кириллицей: вырезать? транслитерировать? экранировать в `%XX`-формат? не трогать?)
- обеспечить уникальность, когда возможны дублирующиеся описания на человеческом языке (что ограничивать обычно вредно)

Известный устоявшийся перевод, кроме англицизма "слаг", мне неизвестен, и, возможно, не существует вовсе.

---

Но бывает и иначе. Реже случается, что их уникальностью пренебрегают.

То, что используется здесь, на Stack Exchange:

```
/{сущности}/{id}/{название}
                 ^^^^^^^^^^ вот это
```

...по приведённому определению slug'ом не является, поскольку не участвует в поиске записи, поиск происходит только по `id`, а на месте сегмента `{название}` реально может быть [любой мусор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/745157/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8C%D1%91%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE,-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE).

Хотя если при обсуждении кто-то назовёт последний сегмент slug'ом, я пойму, что он имеет в виду **идентификатор для человека** (необязательно уникальный технически).

Получается, вот ещё одно определение, которым пользуются на практике. А значит, термин не является однозначным.

---

Я мог бы предложить несколько вариантов перевода, возможно даже в процессе обсуждения здесь на чём-то остановимся, но донести это до широкой общественности видится мне задачей практически невыполнимой.

Comment: Алексей [предлагал](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41149028#41149028) пару ссылок, думаете стоит добавить в ответ?

Comment: @AK ну, я на них не опирался, это не мои ссылки :) Свои я добавлю. Можете добавить свои в вопрос, к примеру.

Answer (score 1):

В большинстве своём `slug` это часть ЧПУ 
(пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/**questions**/ )
Если же хотите дать ему определение отличное от "слаг" то называйте его к примеру "текстовым идентификатором страницы" или "человекопонятным идентификатором страницы" ввиду того, что слаг почти во всех системах уникален для каждой страницы.

*обычно "текстовый идентификатор страницы" это отформатированный заголовок страницы

Answer (score -1):

Рад сообщить, что я являюсь одним из разработчиков плагина [MobiDevices Translate URL](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/mobidevices-translate-url) для перевода `slug`. Наш плагин работает на базе Яндекс.Переводчика, поэтому для работы нужно получить собственный API-ключ, но это очень просто. Полная настройка выглядит так:

1. Установите плагин **MobiDevices Translate URL** через магазин WordPress или поместить файл плагина в папку */wp-content/plugins/*;
2. Получите личный API-ключ для Яндекс.Переводчика по этой ссылке [translate.yandex.ru/developers/keys](https://translate.yandex.ru/developers/keys);
3. В WordPress зайдите в «Настройки => MobiDevices Translate UR»;
4. В поле введите API-ключ, полученный во втором пункте;
5. Активируйте плагин;
6. Наслаждайтесь автоматическим переводом URL и названий медиафайлов!

Comment: Вопрос был по терминологии, а не по переводу самого slug.