# имя категории не передается в урле

Tags: php

код такой

у меня есть раздел сериала

Файл serial.php

```
<?php
require_once "admin/config.php";
include "header.php"; 
$sql = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM `category` 
        ;
") or die(mysql_error());
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $rows[] = $r;
}

/* 
* вывод списка новостей
* в списке сразу создаем ссылку на страницу,
* где будет отображаться полная новость
*/
foreach($rows as $row){
?>


<div id="armenian_serials">

    <div id="armenian_serials_big">

        <div class="armenian_serials_in">
             <img src='uploads/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>' `class="serials_image" />` 
                <div class="armenian_serials_title">

                    <a href="category.php?category_name=<?php echo $row['name']; `?> " ><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a>`
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>


<?php 
    }
    ?>
<?php 
    include "footer.php";
?>
```

Файл category.php

```
<?php
require_once "admin/config.php";
include "header.php"; 



if(isset($_GET['name'])){ 
    $sqlQuery = "
    SELECT * FROM `serials` 
                WHERE `category_name` = ".$_GET['name'].";
        ";
        }else{
        $sqlQuery = "
            SELECT * FROM `serials`;
        ";
    }
    // делаем запрос к бд и получаем новости
    $sql = mysql_query($sqlQuery) or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $rows[] = $r;
    }

    /* 
    * вывод списка новостей
    * в списке сразу создаем ссылку на страницу,
    * где будет отображаться полная новость
    */
    foreach($rows as $row){
?>
<div id="news_center_div">
<h1 class="title_news"><?php echo $row['eng_title']; ?></h1>
<p class='text_news'>  <img src='uploads/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>
  <?php echo $row['eng_text']; ?>     </p>
 </div>
    <?php
            }
            ?>
    <?php 
        include "footer.php";
    ?>
```

Comment: Но ведь вы пишете `$_GET['name']`, а должны были `$_GET['category_name']`

Comment: Кстати, на будущее: принято передавать имя не особо принято, нужно передавать либо id (первичный ключ), потому что int (быстро и т.п.), либо [человекопонятный slug](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/745145/213987)

Comment: Unknown column 'anun' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1):

Вы передаёте в запросе переменную `category_name`

```
<a href="category.php?category_name=<?php echo $row['name']; `?> " ><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a>`
```

А потом почему-то ожидаете не `$_GET['category_name']`, `$_GET['name']`.

Приведите к единому виду:

Либо пишите `$_GET['category_name']` либо `<a href="category.php?name=`

Comment: а теперь пишет Unknown column 'anun' in 'where clause'

Comment: Unknown column 'anun' in 'where clause'

Comment: @gor вы не во всех местах поправили: там чуть ниже ещё есть такое же вхождение

Comment: @Gor Вы не видите. что в строке с WHERE точно такое же выражение $_GET['name'] есть?